# Gmaps4rails zoom not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

My `gmaps` `zoom` isn't working. Here's the code:

```
=gmaps("map_options" => {"zoom" => 20},"markers" => { "data" => @maps_json })
```

Is there something wrong that I'm doing with this implementation?

Answer (score 5):

Found this:

```
 = gmaps("map_options" => {"zoom" => 15, "auto_zoom" => false},"markers" => { "data" => @maps_json })
```

Comment: Good catch, many people ask for the auto_adjust by default which has this kind of drawbacks. Could you edit the doc?